# How can I stop an Electron app from restarting itself after using app.relaunch?

Tags: node.js, windows, process, electron

I was playing around with the [`app.relaunch`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprelaunchoptions) API that will restart my app when closing it.

I used it like so (vastly reduced example, so hopefully it works. Don't want to try running this again):

```
app.on("ready", () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow();
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    app.relaunch();
    app.quit();
});
```

This is a bit stupid, but now, I am stuck in a relaunch loop.

I tried force-closing all 5 Electron.exe processes that are running on my machine via Task Manager, but it keeps restarting.

How can I end this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this was a bit obvious in retrospect, but I just removed the `app.relaunch()` statement, rebuilt the app, and then stopped it. Now it launches the new version which doesn't have the relaunch code in it.

You can also delete your `main.js` file if you're not packaged. If you are packaged, you could just delete your exe, so it can't find it upon relaunching.